# Why is 49, 50, 51, 52 stored in the array when I declare testArray[] = {'1','2','3','4','5'}? (C programming)

Tags: c

Why is 49, 50, 51, 52 stored in the array when I declare testArray[] = {'1','2','3','4','5'}?
How should i initialize a string array? Thanks

Comment: Don't forget the zero terminator!

Comment: A explanation of pmg's short comment: If that is a string array (char *'s to zero terminated char arrays), you should be initializing with strings using double quotes rather than with the single quote: "1" not '1'.  Also as people mentioned, the values (49,...) are ASCII and will be output correctly when you use printf or any other string output function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are initialising the array with *characters*, and what is stored in the array are the ASCII values of those characters.

You can print the character values using something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(testArray)/sizeof(testArray[0]); i++) {
    printf("character '%c', ASCII value %d\n", testArray[i], testArray[i]);
}
```

The first value printed with `%c` interprets the number as the ASCII value of the *character* to print. The same value printed with `%d` prints the number itself.

Answer (score 4):

Because those are the ASCII codes for the number characters. To have a string array you have to do something like this:

```
char *testArray[] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted an array of numeric values, it should have been initialized as `{1,2,3,4,5}`. Putting the numerals in single quotes means they are characters, and the 49, 50, 51,... you are seeing are the ASCII codes for the characters '1', '2', '3', '4'.

Answer (score 1):

because 49, 50, 51 are the [ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/) for 1,2,3...
You're initializing an array of characters, not strings

Answer (score 1):

Because chars are actually stored as their corresponding value in ASCII.

You can declare your string as follows:

```
char * myString = "String";
```

Comment: `const char * myString = "String";` please :)